# Calculate the eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

We calculate the eigenvectors for the matrix 
$$
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{A} = \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      2 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & -1 & 3 \\
    \end{array}
  \right)
\end{equation*}
$$

First, I calculted the eigenvalue polynomial $\det(\mathbf{A}-\lambda \mathbf{I})=0$, and got triple overlapping eigenvalues $\lambda=2$
$$\begin{equation*}
  \mathbf{A} - \lambda \mathbf{I} = \left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      1 & -1 & 1 \\
      1 & -1 & 1 \\
    \end{array}
  \right)
\end{equation*}$$

So, I got only two eigenvectors $x_1=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
      1 \\
      1 \\
      0 \\
    \end{array} \right)$
and $x_2=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
      0 \\
      1 \\
      1 \\
    \end{array} \right)$. So the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is a degenerate matrix.

Did I calculate it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are correct, but that does not mean that $A$ is a degenerate matrix, just that $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Just one little thing:
$x_1=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
      1 \\
      1 \\
      0 \\
    \end{array} \right)$
and $x_2=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
      0 \\
      1 \\
      1 \\
    \end{array} \right)$ are **not** the only eigenvectors but every vector in the whole subspace $\operatorname{span}\left(\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
      1 \\
      1 \\
      0 \\
    \end{array} \right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
      0 \\
      1 \\
      1 \\
    \end{array} \right)\right)$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my blunder. In this case, A is not degenerate. Is a degenerate matrix always undiagonalizable? No? There is not relation between degenerate and diagonalizable, right?

Comment: The last sentence is correct, there is no relation. A diagonalizable matrix might be degenerated or not, and a degenerate matrix might be diagonalizable or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the correctness of your eigenvectors if you apply the matrix on them.

By the way: Since there is only one not-zero entry (2) in the first row of the matrix and this is the first entry, this is the only candidate for an eigenwert.

Comment: Thank you. It is a good way to check them.

Comment: This is my first time to see this method(only one not-zero entry (2) in the first row). Is it a usual method for calculating the eigenvalues? How does it come? What's the principle?

Comment: Yes very unusual (I just edited it: it only works if the entry is also on the diagonal). You should always do it your way - that's standard.

Comment: That is not even correct but $2$ has to be (at least) *one* eigenvalue in this case